# .filter() - example of how to use the val, arr and idx arguments properly?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to determine how .filter() works.

I want to find those elements which match the regex provided, and build a `newArray` not of *those* elements, but of those elements which immediately follow them in the original array.

What is wrong with the below attempt?

```
function searchNames( logins ){
    var regex =/^\.|\.$/;
    var newArray = logins.filter(function(el,idx,arr){
        if (regex.test(el)) {
            console.log('desired return value is '+arr[idx+1]);
            return arr[idx + 1]; // but I get the original 'el' instead
        }
    });
    console.log(newArray);
}

searchNames([ "foo", "foo@bar.com", "bar", "bar@foo.com", ".foo", "food@bar.com" ]);
```

Are there no examples online of something like this? I sure can't find one.

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't really the best application for `.filter()`. JavaScript doesn't have a `.partition()` method, but that'd be a good first pass: group pairs of values so that you can work with an array of arrays. Then, `.filter()` would be easy.

Comment: Oh, and the issue with your code is that `.filter()` expects the callback function to just return `true` or `false`; it doesn't use the values to build a new array. That's what `.map()` does.

Comment: I would use .map() but the assignment demands that one use .filter()...  Found out that you can use && to conditionally return the elements you want, based upon the property of a neighboring element (which is found with idx and arr). Clever stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can't `return` the element you want in the new array from the callback. The [`filter` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) does expect a *boolean result* whether the *current* element should be in the result array. In your case, that would be

```
var newArray = logins.filter(function(el,idx,arr){
    return idx > 0 && regex.test(arr[idx-1]);
});
```